# How to send a IFrame in email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, iframe

How can i send a iframe in email body.This is how i am simply sending a mail.

```
        string getemail = textbox_email.Text;
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(getemail);
        message.Subject = "Hello";
        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sendingemail");
        message.Body = "This is message body";
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendingemail", "password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(message);
        Response.Write("Sent");
```

This is iframe in html.Actully iframe will contain the youtube video link.

```
<iframe id="iframe" runat="server" src="http://www.w3schools.com"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

How can i send it in email body?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mailmsg.IsBodyHtml=true;

Comment: thanks but how to combine/attach a iframe in body?

Comment: i think gmail or any other noted smtps would block your iframes.i checked your code and gamil is blocking it.you probably need to look for a different option.Here is the so post on alternatives for IFRAMES http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719053/loading-dynamic-div-content-with-jquery-from-a-url

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property or [AlternativeViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to send HTML.

If you expect that client will render content inside your IFrame it very likely not to happen due to security restrictions in mail clients (similar to blocking external images).

Answer (score 0):

While it IS extremely unlikely that your email recipient's client will render the iframe, depending on your intended goal, you may want to look into the DownloadString method of the WebClient class.

Comment: Surprisingly many, but certainly not all, email clients support rendering iframes https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/